# In Dune, what type of name is Chani?

Tags: history-of, dune, names

Is is Jewish, Arabic, European etc?

**Does anyone know the origin of the name Chani?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from Hebrew. [Think Baby Names](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Chani) gives the following derivation;

> Chani /cha-ni/ [2 sylls.] as a name for girls is of Hebrew derivation, and the name Chani means "He (God) has favored me". Chani is an alternate form, with the suffix -i, of [Chana](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Chana) (Hebrew): version of [Hannah](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Hannah).

Comment: Hmm. That would imply it is pronounced with the 'ch' as in loch or Bach, but all the adaptations have always pronounced it with a ch as in church.

Comment: To sum up the above definition in one word, Chani can also mean simply "grace".